# Rewrite node diplay with Views

Tags: views

I have created a views page ?q=node/% which overrides the default node display with Views. (very cool) My related taxonomy blocks stopped working though. Maybe there is something I do not know? Info below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't understand - you can see that the path is `node/%`, so why would you expect the `%` to ever contain a taxonomy term ID?!

Comment: well, when I turn the views page off, the url is node/32 for example and everything works, isn't it the same as node/%? Where is this Taxonomy term ID being taken from?

Comment: I might be misunderstanding, but it seems you've set up the filter to get the taxonomy term ID from the URL - but it's not in the URL, the node id is

Comment: May sound stupid :) but I have two questions, by default, where is this Taxonomy term ID being taken from, as I do not see it in the URL? Is it possible to include the Taxonomy term ID in the node/% views page?