# Views, When the filter value is NOT available

Tags: views

Cannot figure this out. In views, when creating a contextual filter and set up 'Provide default value' as below. Where are these values being taken from? - Taxonomy term ID from URL, User ID from URL etc... when I see that the current url is **mydomain.com/?q=node/38** and cannot see them in the url at all.

[image]

Comment: I'm not following. 38 is in the current url. Are you getting no results at all or something else?

Comment: I have related blocks that use taxonomy term ID from URL, they work fine but when I override the node page with a views page /node/%, all related blocks stop working. They cannot find the taxonomy term id but the url is still the same - node/nid. Thats why I am trying to get deeper into this. Thank you!

Comment: in the example above, 38 is the nid, where are both taxonomy term id and user id being taken from?

Comment: *User ID from URL* would be used if you're visiting a profile page (user/%user). The same goes for *Taxonomy term ID from URL*.

Comment: If you update your question with more information of what you have and what you want to achieve, I might be able to give you a proper answer.

Comment: @hampusn see http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/97009/rewrite-node-diplay-with-views

Comment: In general, I want to override the node display with Views, but then my related taxonomy blocks stop working...

Comment: Well, regarding *this* question, the ID is retrieved from the URL. When a taxonomy ID isn't present in the URL (as in your case), it would seem that the *Load default filter from node page, that's good for related taxonomy blocks* option fetches some IDs from the node.